# Refactor Jquery function to be reusable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, refactoring

I wrote a Function that takes the offset of a container compares it to the windows scrolltop on scroll and fades in the content once the container is "X" amount of pixels from the top of viewport. Right now the function is specific to one container. I have another container on the page which I would like to run the same function on but being fairly new to jquery/javascript cannot figure out a way to refactor for reuse.

```
$(function(){
    // Get the offset of container and compare it to $(window).scrollTop
    var cont = $('.intro__skills-cont');
    var contPos = cont.offset().top;
    var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    // Hide skillsContainer
    cont.addClass('is-hidden');

    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        windowPos = $(this).scrollTop();

        if(windowPos > contPos - 250) {
            cont.removeClass('.is-hidden');
            cont.addClass('is-fading-up');
        }

    }); // end window scroll

});
```

This is my current HTML Structure I would like to be able to run function on

```
    <div class="intro__skills-cont">
        <div class="intro__skills-design">
            <svg><use xlink:href="#shape-design" /></svg>
            <h3 class="intro__skills-title">Design</h3>
            <p class="intro__skills-sum">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam fugit illo pariatur ad dicta mollitia nulla provident repellendus doloribus at quam veniam cumque vitae neque, cupiditate, iusto, accusamus, tenetur perferendis.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="intro__skills-dev">
            <svg><use xlink:href="#shape-dev" /></svg>
            <h3 class="intro__skills-title">Development</h3>
            <p class="intro__skills-sum">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam fugit illo pariatur ad dicta mollitia nulla provident repellendus doloribus at quam veniam cumque vitae neque, cupiditate, iusto, accusamus, tenetur perferendis.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="portfolio">
    <h2 class="intro__title">Portfolio</h2>
    <div class="portfolio__gallery">
    </div>
</div>
```

I know this may seem like I am asking for free work but really just looking for a push in the right direction.

This is my latest attempt but it errors out on contPos
any help is greatly appreciated. Cheers!

```
function fadeUp(containerClass) {
    var cont = "$('." + containerClass + "')";
    var contPos = cont.offset().top;
    var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop();

    cont.addClass('is-hidden');

    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        windowPos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(windowPos > contPos - 250) {
            cont.removeClass('.is-hidden');
            cont.addClass('is-fading-up');
        }
    });


}

fadeUp('intro__skils-cont');
```

Comment: Hint: take the `$(window).scroll` out of the function, and put the function inside `$(window).scroll` instead, refactoring as necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you write the function to take a jQuery object. Then you can use whatever selector you want when calling it. Also, you should write it to handle multiple elements. You could use `.each()` for this.

```
function fadeUp($elements) {
    $elements.each(function() {
        var $element = $(this),
            elementPos = $element.offset().top;
        $element.addClass('is-hidden');
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > (elementPos - 250)) {
                $element.removeClass('is-hidden');
                $element.addClass('is-fading-up');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

You can then call like this:

```
fadeUp($('.intro__skills-cont'));
fadeUp($('.intro__skills-dev'));
```

Or this:

```
fadeUp($('.intro__skills-cont, .intro__skills-dev'));
```

Or put a "container" class on all the containers, and then use;

```
fadeUp($('.container'));
```

Comment: Thanks you John. That definitely works perfectly. One newbie question so by running .each() and setting $element = $(this) that is what would allow me to put the same "container" class on all my containers yet have it run independently on each one?

Comment: @VinceBrown - Yes. The function given to `$(window).scroll()` is a closure with the independent variables `elementPos` and `$element`. The closure remembers the values of those variables when it is created, and for each iteration of the `.each()` function, those variables have different values. That is, for each element, an event handler is registered for the window scroll event, with the event callback referring to that element.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the line `var cont = "$('." + containerClass + "')";`.  You want to pass the locator to `$()`, not create the string `"$(intro__skills-cont)"`.

You could try something like

```
function fadeUp(container) {   
    var cont = $(container);
    //...
}

fadeUp('.intro__skills-cont');
```

You'll note that I've not prepended the `'.'` to the locator.  That has the advantage of allowing you to pass in DOM objects as well as jQuery locators.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways you can do it
based on your current fadeUp function

```
function fadeUp(containerClass) {
    var cont = $('.'+containerClass);
    var contPos = cont.offset().top;
    var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop();

    cont.addClass('is-hidden');

    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        windowPos = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(windowPos > contPos - 250) {
            cont.removeClass('.is-hidden');
            cont.addClass('is-fading-up');
        }
    });
}
```